# Connecting two laptops using ad hoc network in Windows

Tags: windows-xp, networking, wireless-networking, ad-hoc-network

I want to test a chat server that I have made. For that I want to connect two laptops, one having Windows XP and the other having Windows 7.

I know it is possible to make an ad hoc network and then ping the two laptops, but I am not aware of the whole procedure. I have tried to make an ad hoc network on the laptop having Windows XP, but I could not understand what to do next. Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

1. Initiate the ad-hoc network from one machine.
2. Join the ad-hoc network from the other machine. It should show up almost like any other Wi-Fi network.
3. Both machines will assign themselves IPv4 link-local addresses in the 169.254.x.x range (Microsoft sometimes calls these "APIPA" addresses). Use the Windows GUI or "ipconfig /all" at the command prompt to learn what 169.254.x.x addresses each machine gave itself.
4. Ping one machine's 169.254.x.x address from the other machine.
5. If the ping worked, fire up your chat server on one machine, and try to connect to it from the other one. Tell your chat client to connect to the 169.254.x.x address of the server machine.